# how to read if statement conditions from text file

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I need to read several `if` statement conditions from a text file that looks like this:

```
@
x>4
x<8
y>45
*
x>8
y>9
%%%%%%
```

I want to know if there is a way to read the full `"x>5"` with C++ and save it to use as a condition for an `if` statement, like:

```
if(condition1&&condition2){

do ...

}
```

Now I am reading the line, checking for a `<` or `>` and saving that in a `bool` variable, later extracting the number to a `double` variable. But the problem is I need to check for many conditions, and doing `if(bool)` and `if(> or <double)` is too long. I thought there might be another way.

Comment: What are the parsing rules for your 'condition file'? Do all conditions in the file need to hold, a subset, or just one? Where would the variables come from?

Comment: Nothing built into the language. You will have to do the grunt work yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: There may be a better way than what you are doing. If you show what you have so far, odds are good we can make suggestions, but that's not really the point of Stack Overflow. If you have code that works that you believe could work better, you should ask at Code Review. I strongly recommend reading through their [help pages on asking questions first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) so you can formulate a question that will be well-received. If your code doesn't work, that's what we do here. Show it and we'll help fix it.

Comment: `string line; getline(input, line); if (line == "@" ) ...; else if (line == "x>4") { if (x > 4) cout << "Bob's your uncle.\n"; else cout << "Swing and a miss.\n"; } else if (line == "x<8") if (x < 8) cout << "Yes, Pinky, take over the world.\n"; else cout << "Curses, foiled again.\n"; }` et cetera.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ shunting yard algorithm".

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the parse rules for your file. I don't know what `@`, `*`, and `%%%%%` are supposed to imply.

There's nothing built into the language that will just do this for you. (Nor is there in any other programming language I've ever used.)

This sounds like a cool programming assignment, but you're going to have to do what you need to do with any sufficiently complicated programming task.

- Identify the basic problem
- Break it down into small pieces you understand
- Implement and test each piece, one at a time
- Assemble the working pieces into a complete solution

For this, you have to read the file. You have to then parse each line so you know what it's trying to do. And then somehow you have to turn that into logic that tests the conditions in question.

Then you have to wrap it all -- get your x and y, then test against the various conditions from the file.

None of this is hard, although when I was a newbie (a long time ago), I think this would probably have taken me a few hours. If you think this is a 15-minute problem, then you're better than I was.

Programming is fun, but it takes dedication.

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if we created a *Condition* class?
Hmmmm.

```
    typedef bool (*Comparison_Function)(int a, int b);           

   class Condition
    {
      public:  
        Condition(int& variable,
                  Comparison_Function p_operator_fun,
                  int  constant)
        : m_variable(variable),
          m_p_operator(p_operator_fun),
          m_constant(constant)
        { ; }
      private:
          int& m_variable;
          Comparison_Function m_p_operator;
          int  m_constant;
    };
```

The above class represents a *condition* that has a variable, a comparison operator and a constant.

We can then upgrade and have an "evaluation" method:

```
class Condition
{
  public:  
    //...
    bool evaluate()
    {
         return m_p_operator(m_variable, m_constant);
    }
};
```

To store these conditions, you could use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Condition> Condition_Container;
```

**Edit 1:  Evaluating Conditions**
You could access the conditions specifically or by variable index:

```
if (Condition_Container[0].evaluate() && Condition_Container[1].evaluate())
{
}
```

**Edit 2: Reading a Condition**
The `Condition` class could overload `operator>>` to read in a condition from the input file:

```
class Condition
{
  public:
    //...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Condition& c);
  //...
};

int x;
int y;
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Condition& c)
{
   char variable_name;
   char operator_symbol;
   input >> variable_name;
   if (variable_name == x) c.m_variable = x;
   else c.m_variable = y;
   input >> operator_symbol;
   if (operator_symbol == '<') c.m_p_operator = std::less;
   input >> c.m_constant;
   return input;
}
```

*Note:  You may want to change the variable member to a pointer in order to use a default constructor.*